# Random extrapolation of dataset

Tags: python, dataset

I would like to know how to make an extrapolation of the dataset below at random, based on the history having as target variable the column 'Total Product' (Which would be blank).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you define `extrapolation of the dataset below at random` please ? It's not clear to me what results you are expecting.

Comment: I want to extend the dataset (minus 1 column) and then use multiple linear regression to predict the values

Comment: So not completely at random right ? What have you tried so far ?